# Remove the [ansi-c] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

There are currently 97 questions tagged `[ansi-c]`.

All of the questions are also tagged `[c]` (I added that tag to the few that didn't have it).

I recommend getting rid of the `[ansi-c]` tag entirely.  At best it is ambiguous, since "ANSI C" is used frequently to refer to C89/C90, but C99 is also an ANSI standard.

Questions about `[c]` should be assumed to be about standard C.  If there is a need to specify which C standard the question is about, `[c90]` or `[c99]` should be used.  If a variant of C is being used (e.g., GNU C), then the question should be tagged appropriately.

Comment: I fully agree - only specific versions and non-standard extension should get specific tags.

Comment: Are you also going to add specific version tags, or just nuke [ansi-c] ?

Comment: @Tim:  Looking over the list, now that they all have the `[c]` tag, with only a couple of exceptions, I'd say the `[ansi-c]` tag should just be nuked.

Comment: I just went through all and added specific tags for the few questions that were missing one, so in my opinion `[ansi-c]` is safe to remove.

Comment: Gets my vote. I can't imagine anyone else who is active in the tag enough to care would object.

Comment: Though I don't expect to see t used much, you can also expect [K&R-c] for questions concerning the pre-standardization language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eradicated `[ansi-c]`.  It was a lot of questions, but I figured that since it's Saturday, no one is using Stack Overflow for real work anyway (if anyone ever does real work on Stack Overflow...).

Comment: I use it **alot** on Saturday! It's a day off!

Comment: Goodbye ansi-c , we hardly knew ya.